# H Tree using recursion python

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

I've been trying to code this, but it's not working and I'm confused.

Use recursion to draw the “H-Tree” fractal.

The H-Tree fractal is defined as follows:

1. Begin with the letter H. The Three lines of the H are all of the same length, as shown in the first image. This is an H-Tree of order 0.
2. The letter H has four endpoints. Draw an H centered at each of the four endpoints, as shown in the second image. These H’s are half the size of the previous H. This is an 
   H-Tree of order 1.
3. Repeat step 2 to create an H-Tree fractal of higher orders, as shown in images 3 and 4.

Your function definition MUST have this format:
    def h_tree(order, center, size):
    Where:
order is is the order of the fractal, as described above
center is the center point of the H-Tree, in the format [x, y]
size is the length of each of the lines in the H

Here's my code:

```
import turtle

#reverse method
def reverse_string(string):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return string
    else:
        return reverse_string(string[1:]) + string[0]

#fractal method
def h_tree(order, center, size):
    if order == 0:
        draw_turtle([0,0], 300)
    else:
        get_endpoints(center, size)

        h_tree(order-1, ep1, size)
        h_tree(order-1, ep2, size)
        h_tree(order-1, ep3, size)
        h_tree(order-1, ep4, size)


def draw_turtle(center, size):
    turtle.showturtle()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(center)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(size/2)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(size/2)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(size)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(center)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(size/2)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(size/2)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(size)


    turtle.done()

def get_endpoints(center, size):
    ep1 = center[0] + size/2
    ep2 = center[1] + size/2
    ep3 = center[0] + size/2
    ep4 = center[1] + size/2
    return [ep1, ep2, ep3, ep4]


'''
The animate function needs to take in an x and y as arguments
because of how we are calling it from the main function.
Since it is being called when the mouse is clicked, it is
required to take the x,y location of the mouse at the time
of the click. You do not need to use the x,y for anything, so
just leave them there as parameters but you do not need to use 
them inside your function.
'''
'''
def animate(x, y):
    return
'''
def main():

    # Q1 - call the recursive reverse_string() function
    print(reverse_string("desserts"))
    print(reverse_string("flow"))
    print(reverse_string("abcdefg"))

    # Q2 - call the recursive H-Tree fractal function
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    h_tree(2, [0, 0], 300)

    turtle.done()
'''
    # Q3 - when the mouse is clicked in the turtle window,
    # call the animate() function to display a spinning star
    turtle.onscreenclick(animate)
'''    

main()
```

Comment: one thing I see is that `get_endpoints(center, size)` does not return any of the 'ep's , so change that to `ep1, ep2, ep3, ep4 =  get_endpoints(center, size)`

Comment: When I try your code, there are many errors it is giving. Have you tested this at all? What questions do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic that's basically sound, though not the way I'd do it, but needs some patching.  Mostly because you didn't follow through on your own logic.  You know that `h_tree()` takes a position (pair of numbers) as its second argument but you only passed a single number (if even that, as @SRTHellKitty notes, you forgot to save the result of `get_endpoints()`).  You also forgot to reduce `size` by half on the recursive call.  You miscalculated two of the end points. And you didn't leave the turtle in its original orientation at the end of `draw_turtle()` which would have left you with half the H figures rotated, should you get it working.

Below is the repaired code -- I've pulled out your code for Q1 since it wasn't related to the problems you are asking about:

```
import turtle

def h_tree(order, center, size):
    draw_turtle(center, size)

    if order > 0:
        ep1, ep2, ep3, ep4 = get_endpoints(center, size)

        h_tree(order - 1, (ep1, ep2), size / 2)
        h_tree(order - 1, (ep1, ep4), size / 2)
        h_tree(order - 1, (ep3, ep2), size / 2)
        h_tree(order - 1, (ep3, ep4), size / 2)

def draw_turtle(center, size):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(center)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.forward(size / 2)  # right side of H
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(size / 2)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(size)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(center)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.right(90)  # left side of H
    turtle.forward(size / 2)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(size / 2)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.forward(size)

    turtle.right(90)  # return turtle to original orientation

def get_endpoints(center, size):
    ep1 = center[0] + size / 2
    ep2 = center[1] + size / 2
    ep3 = center[0] - size / 2
    ep4 = center[1] - size / 2

    return ep1, ep2, ep3, ep4

def main():

    turtle.speed('fastest')

    h_tree(2, (0, 0), 300)

    turtle.hideturtle()

    turtle.done()

main()
```

[image]